# Equal Width monospace text with changing colors in the same line

Tags: color, width, typewriter

I'm trying to create something like the following in Latex:

[image]

I've tried to `\usepackage{color}` and put this:

```
\ssmall\begin{ttfamily}
\begin{center}
\colorbox{yellow}{100101000010111011100100000110010000011001000001100100110110010011000101000101100100010000101011000010101100001010101100001}
\colorbox{green}{\#}\colorbox{cyan}{s}----S---\colorbox{cyan}{es}--z-0----\colorbox{cyan}{es}----1---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----2---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----3---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----4---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----5---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----6---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----7---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----8---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----9-z--\colorbox{cyan}{es}----E---\colorbox{cyan}{e}
\end{center}
\end{ttfamily}
```

But it comes out like this:

[image]

Why is every color change in the bottom line gives a padding to the characters? How can I reduce that?

Comment: the padding is `\fboxsep`, next time please provide a complete test document not just a fragment, it makes it much easier to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\setlength\oddsidemargin{-5cm}
\setlength\textwidth{40cm}
\setlength\paperwidth{60cm}
\begin{document}

\small\begin{ttfamily}
\begin{center}\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\colorbox{yellow}{100101000010111011100100000110010000011001000001100100110110010011000101000101100100010000101011000010101100001010101100001}
\colorbox{green}{\#}\colorbox{cyan}{s}----S---\colorbox{cyan}{es}--z-0----\colorbox{cyan}{es}----1---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----2---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----3---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----4---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----5---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----6---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----7---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----8---\colorbox{cyan}{es}----9-z--\colorbox{cyan}{es}----E---\colorbox{cyan}{e}
\end{center}
\end{ttfamily}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I have to reset `\fboxsep` after it was set to `{0pt}`?

Comment: @DoronBehar it is a local setting so it ends at the current group (`\end{center}` here)  so no need to set it back explicitly